# How to validate Json Path string on the browser

Tags: javascript, json, validation, browser, jsonpath

I have this scenario where a user should supply me a json path which will later on be evaluated eagerly on demand. This means I need somehow to use a regular expression or any other library which can validate the json path on client side without an actual schema.

Example given json path: `$.phoneNumbers[:1].type`

So the handler should be like `isStringJsonPath(userExp:string) => boolean`.

I have only found Java/other backend languages solutions so far, like this: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033179/is-there-anyway-to-validate-if-a-syntax-of-jsonpath-is-correct

Comment: hey @jessica-98. Thanks, but this thread is for Java only. I need pure native (or external library) Javascript solution, so it could be run on browser context

Comment: anyone else ????